# Why is my context variable is not changing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, amazon-cognito

I'm starting to learn React, and I'm breaking my head with a simple problem.

I've created a context variable, to store my authentication state, however the value of isAuthenticated is not been updated by setIsAuthenticated as follows:

auth.js

```
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

const MyContext = createContext();

function AuthProvider({ children }){
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  async function handleLogin(value){
    setIsAuthenticated(value);
  }
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ isAuthenticated, handleLogin}}>
      { children }
    </MyContext.Provider>
  )
}

export { MyContext, AuthProvider };
```

Login.js

```
const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const userData = {
        Username: email,
        Pool: UserPool
    };


    const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser( userData );
    const authenticationData = {
        Username: email,
        Password: password
    };
    var authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails( authenticationData );

    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: result => {
            handleLogin(true);
        },
        onFailure: err => {
            handleLogin(false);
        }
    });
}
```

When I call onSucess or onFailure, the handleLogin function is not changing isAuthenticated, but handleLogin function is invoked.

Why setIsAuthenticated is not changing the value?

Edit: Adding my app file

```
import {React} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import MainRoutes from './routes';
import {AuthProvider} from './providers/auth'
 
const cookies = new Cookies();

export default function App() {
  return (
      <AuthProvider>
        <div class="container">
          <MainRoutes />
        </div>
      </AuthProvider>
    )
}
```

Comment: Is your top level component wrapped inside AuthProvider?

Comment: `async` in `handleLogin`  is not necessary I think

Comment: Yes, I'm wrapping my entire app with AuthProvider

Comment: Are you sure you are getting `handleLogin` and `isAuthenticated` (whose value did not change) from the context correctly?

Comment: I've tested logging isAuthenticated value after setIsAuthenticated was invoked, and it stayed with same value (inside handeLogin)